# gcloud and python 2.7 encoding

Tags: python, node.js, encoding, ascii, gcloud

I am facing the problem with `Google Cloud SDK`

So, I have Git Bash on Windows 10, and I am trying to deploy my `Node.js` App through `gcloud`

```
gcloud app deploy
```

But I get this error

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (UnicodeDecodeError): 'ascii' codec can't decode
>   byte 0xc4 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

I can't find the solution, so, what recommendations you can give?

Comment: So, I found a problem - my path to the file contains Russian letters. And my question - how can I force python read Russian letters?

Comment: This is essentially a bug in the code. Can you run `gcloud feedback` to report the issue, so it can be addressed in future release.